# error while adding new organization in hyperledger fabric -1.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have downloaded and setup the hyperledger fabric network in my CentOs system. I am able to start the first network with default two organization (Org1 and Org2). Also each organization is having two peers(peer0, peer1). Now I am trying add one more Organization with one peer.

I have made changes in below files

1. first-network/crypto-config.yaml
2. first-network/configtx.yaml
3. first-network/docker-compose-cli.yaml
4. first-network/base/docker-compose-base.yaml
5. first-network/script/script.sh

now while trying to up the network. Below exception is coming

```
Having all peers join the channel...
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
CORE_PEER_ID=cli
CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
2017-09-06 06:40:53.134 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2017-09-06 06:40:53.134 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-09-06 06:40:53.136 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2017-09-06 06:40:53.136 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 004 Sign: plaintext: 0A89070A5B08011A0B08F5B0BECD0510...742FDE921B171A080A000A000A000A00
2017-09-06 06:40:53.136 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 005 Sign: digest: 152A1C5D481840FB755E98925E0D346271894F15AB69E694C03BEC962E523A50
Error: proposal failed (err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Failed to deserialize creator identity, err Expected MSP ID org1MSP, received Org1MSP)
Usage:
  peer channel join [flags]

Flags:
  -b, --blockpath string   Path to file containing genesis block

Global Flags:
      --cafile string              Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --logging-level string       Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
  -o, --orderer string             Ordering service endpoint
      --test.coverprofile string   Done (default "coverage.cov")
      --tls                        Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
  -v, --version                    Display current version of fabric peer server

PEER0 failed to join the channel, Retry after 2 seconds
```

Comment: Can you share changes you've made?

Comment: first-network/crypto-config.yaml                                                                                                 # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org3: See "Org1" for full specification
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org3
    Domain: org3.example.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1

Comment: could you lease provide your email id so that I can provide you all the changes I have made.

Comment: > org1MSP, received Org1MSP

Looks like a case sensitivity typo?

Comment: you can find me on Rocket.Chat chat.hyperledger.org @C0rWin.

Comment: @yacovm: We have checked for the typo.Still no luck.